# How to add link tag in html only for production build Vite

Tags: html, vite

I want to add this line in my HTML but only for production build using Vite. How can I do this?

```
<link rel="preload" href="assets/inter-latin-400-normal.woff2" as="font" type="font/woff2" crossorigin="anonymous" />
```

Comment: Vite is serving by html itself or are you using a lib like, react/vue/preact? Any template engines?

Comment: i'm using react , no template engine

Comment: {process.env.NODE_ENV=='"production"?<link>:""}

Comment: To add this condition, I need a component or hook that can edit the head tag. I found react-helmet-async, which is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

this is the solution that works for me: using `react-helmet-async`

```
import { HelmetProvider, Helmet } from "react-helmet-async";

function App() {
...
<HelmetProvider>
    <Helmet>
    {import.meta.env.PROD && <link rel="preload" href="assets/inter-latin-400-normal.woff2" as="font" type="font/woff2" crossOrigin="anonymous" />}
    </Helmet>
...
</HelmetProvider>
}
export default App;
```